# Prove Composite Infinitely Often

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose we let $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ be a non-constant polynomial, and assume that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers.

Prove: There are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $f(n)$ is composite.

Answer (score 6):

For sufficiently large $N$, $|f(N)| > 1$.  Let $p$ be any prime dividing $f(N)$.
For any integer $k$, $f(N+kp)-f(N)$ is divisible by $p$, so  $f(N+kp)$ is also divisible by $p$, and only finitely many of these can be $p$, $0$ or $-p$.

(I'm assuming you're not restricting "composite" to positive integers: otherwise $f(x) = -x^2$ would be a counterexample)

Comment: So basically now, Q.E.D

Comment: No, no restrictions.